# react-particles-js not working into iframe tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, particles

I'm developing components for a landing page in React 16.  I'm using @storybook/react to show components features. Storybook renders components into an iframe. I have a problem when I use react-particles-js. 
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwMEY.png)

I have tested with create-react-app and all is OK, but when i put react-particles-js into iframe tag, it shows the same error.

`import Particles from 'react-particles-js';`

`<Particles/>`
Working ok!

`<iframe> <Particles/> </iframe>`
Not working!

I've also been tracing the library and I think there's some problem in the following piece of code (particle.js - line 1367):

```
Math.sqrt(s * s + o * o) <= e.radius + n.radius && (e.x = t ? t.x : Math.random() * i.width, e.y = t ? t.y : Math.random() * i.height, r.checkOverlap(e));
```